# AngularJs:Log in happening only after clicking twice

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs.

I am developing a small angular app.

My Approach:
My index.html page is having 2 parts, an **ng-view** and a **div with 4 navigation buttons**.The div is initilly hidden using ng-show.ng-show="variable" (a variable is created in the main controller with null value. This variable will turn from Null to true when log in is successful.).On successful login, the navigation div will be vissible, and rest of the things looks good , at least for now.

Issue:
Login button initiats a login function, The login is happening only on clicking the button twice. In the console, i can see, two sucessive SessionIDs are created. The variable turns from null to True on 1st click. still there is on impact on entire page.

Can any one help.

Comment: Can you share some code/fiddle/plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen your code, but think your problem is that you are trying to change view scope and it is not the same scope as your navigation `div` have. In that case you can either modify your navigation div to have the same scope as view have or use `$rootScope`.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.10" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Log-on App</h1>
    <div>
      <ul ng-show="variable">
        <li><a href="#/one">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/two">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/three">Tree</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/fore">Fore</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        controller: 'appController',
        template: '<div ng-show="!variable"><input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Log On" ng-click="login()" /></div>'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]).
  controller('appController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $rootScope.variable = null;
    $scope.login = function() {
      $rootScope.variable = true;
    }
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Cjn2K8IEg0WQZDGVwPIw?p=preview

Other reason that I can think about is that you are trying to modify `$scope` outside of controller. In that case you should call `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$apply()` after you modify scope variables.

**JavaScript**

```
function logOnClick() {
  var $scope,
      div;
  div = document.getElementById('navigationDivId');
  $scope = angular.element(div).scope();
  $scope.variable = true;
  $scope.$digest();
}
```

***EDIT: log-on using remote service***

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        controller: 'appController',
        template: '<form ng-show="!variable"><input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" placeholder="user name"/><br/><input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="password" /><br/><input type="button" value="Log On" ng-click="login()" /></form>'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]).
  factory('appLoginService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var isLogedOn = false,
        user;

    return {
      login: function(name, password) {
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'login',
          params: {
            name: name,
            password: password
          }
        }).
          success(function(data) {
            if(data.status === 'OK' && data.authenticated === true) {
              isLogedOn = true;
              user = data.user;
            }
          }).
          error(function(data) {
            alert('Error!');
          });
      },
      isLoggedOn: function() {
        return isLogedOn;
      },
      getUser: function() {
        return user;
      }
    }
  }]).
  controller('appController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'appLoginService', function($rootScope, $scope, appLoginService) {
    $rootScope.variable = null;
    $scope.login = function() {
      appLoginService.
        login($scope.user, $scope.password).
        success(function() { // <- don't check isLoggedOn directly, wait until response come from server
          $rootScope.variable = appLoginService.isLoggedOn();
        });
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: Thank you Vadim for your valuable reply.

Comment: Let me add, these.
The server used for the project is vertX. In the login part, I have to call a function, with parameter userName and password. I will be returned with a JSON as the reply to my fun call. If the user is authenticated, a key in json object 'status' will be 'ok', otherwise 'denied'. 

Here, I will make variable = true , if status= ok. That was what I was trying.

I am getting this issue only when I use the vertX function. 
suppose I write like variable is set to true when $scope.userName = 'J'. Then the log in is happening on one click.

Comment: here is a plunk of login using remote service that returns JSON: http://plnkr.co/edit/HJQYLLL3XLQamB0rZTj9?p=preview