# Angular requires two clicks to show Google Geocode location

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm new to Angular, and one of the apps I want to build will take the location a user inputs and turn it into coordinates through the Google Geocoding API. I have used Angular's data binding to display the coordinates in the page. But, the button only changes the value after two clicks, even though I'm using a function in the `$rootScope` as advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21526357/1863597).

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pimmen/atnzum13/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$rootScope.position = results[0].geometry.location
```

to this:

```
 $rootScope.$apply(function() {
    $rootScope.position = results[0].geometry.location;
 });
```

You need to tell angular to apply your change to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Right after you assign new value to $rootScope.position simply call:

```
$rootScope.$apply();
```

This notifies Angural about model changes.